# Geocoder: How get all results and order by distance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I know how to use the `near` method to get all results within a certain radius, but how do I get all results and order by distance?

I know I could do something like this:

```
Location.near(my_location, 999999, order: 'distance')
```

However, I would rather skip the radius check altogether and simply get all results sorted by distance.

Comment: Hey, @Godwin. If you felt like my answer solved your problemm, consider marking it as the solution. Also so this doesn't appear on the non-answered lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same issue, and I ended up adding this scope to my geocoded class:

```
class A
  extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

  scope :with_distance_to, ->(point) { select("#{table_name}.*").select("(#{distance_from_sql(point)}) as distance") }
end
```

This will allow you to do `A.with_distance_to(point).order('distance')`

Comment: its giving error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244132/pgsyntaxerror-at-error-syntax-error-at-or-near-rails/33266036#33266036