# Geocoder Sort By Distance Without Proximity Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

Using the `geocoder` gem is it possible to use the distance from a point as a sort criteria but not a filter criteria? I'm looking for a cleaner way than just setting a really large distance like this:

```
Location.near(coordinates, 8_000_000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass an `order` option:

```
Location.near(coordinates, 8_000_000 , order: 'distance')
```

Note that you still have to set a maximum distance though.

Comment: As I said: I'm looking for a cleaner way than setting a really large distance.

Comment: So you want to return **all** locations sorted by distance from a particular point?

Comment: Yes, I don't want any WHERE clauses in the query.

Comment: Just came across this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793235/geocoder-how-get-all-results-and-order-by-distance, which looks like exactly what you want.