# PG::SyntaxError at / ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg

I am getting this error some time and some time not. That is strange.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: SELECT  locations.*, () as
>   distance FROM "locations"  ORDER ...

In line

```
nearby_locations.includes(:events).each do |location|
```

In my Dashboard controller

```
 def home            
    nearby_locations = Location.with_distance_to(remote_ip).order('distance').limit(10)
    @events  = []
    nearby_locations.includes(:events).each do |location|
        @events += location.events.where("publish = true")
    end
end
```

In my Location.rb model

```
geocoded_by :address
extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
  reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

  scope :with_distance_to, ->(point) { select("#{table_name}.*").select("(#{distance_from_sql(point)}) as distance") }
```

Comment: If you run `distance_from_sql(point)` in your model, what does it return?

Comment: @yez  how to do that ?

Comment: It is a method on your `Location` model. You should be able to do `Location.distance_from_point(some_point)` where `some_point` is a point, the same that you were passing to `with_distance_to` scope.

Comment: 2.1.5 :005 > Location.distance_from_sql('122.168.149.228')

 => "3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((27.433 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(27.433 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((77.1 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))" 
2.1.5 :006 >

Comment: @yez output as above

Comment: That looks fine, the next thing I would look at is that in your `dashboard_controller`, that the value of `remote_ip` is not nil. The big issue is that your scope seems to return `nil` for the `distance_from_sql` method during some process.

Comment: @yez it may be the problem becz its sometime showing error and some time not

Comment: @yez thats the problem, any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the errors, you should validate that `remote_ip` in your `dashboard_controller` exists before using the scope you have defined on `Location`.

```
 def home            
  unless remote_ip.blank?
    nearby_locations = Location.with_distance_to(remote_ip).order('distance').limit(10)
    @events  = []
    nearby_locations.includes(:events).each do |location|
        @events += location.events.where("publish = true")
    end
  end
end
```

To really understand the problem, find out how `remote_ip` is blank in the first place and fix that issue.

Comment: problem still persist. problem is in scope :with_distance_to, ->(point) { select("#{table_name}.*").select("(#{distance_from_sql(point)}) as distance") }